# Windows Interaction Issues After Game Launch

Tags: windows-10, interaction

For the past few months, I've been dealing with a problem with Windows that I can't quite figure out. Whenever launching particular game titles such as Overwatch and Fortnite, some applications can no longer be interacted with. I've [recorded a video](https://youtu.be/75Ba2-5YMhs) to show exactly what is happening.

This video is showing the hover interaction of Spotify before and after launching one of these two games.

- Before launching the game, you can see that the application functions normally. (0:00 in Video)
- After launching the game, you can see that the application no longer responds to hovering. (0:10 in video)

FileZilla, Putty, and Spotify are immediately affected during every launch of these applications. Discord, Steam, Battle.net, Premiere, Photoshop, InDesign, Illustrator, and IntelliJ IDEA are affected on an inconsistent basis. When this issue occurs, clicks will be registered with applications located behind the problematic application.

All applications encountering this issue will resume normal functionality when relaunched through the system tray or Task Manager. Applications like Spotify can still play or pause audio using keyboard media keys when this issue occurs.

I noticed that this bug started occurring after I installed the Fall Creators Update in November. I'd like to stay clear of the reset Windows option unless absolutely necessary. I found a similar question called [Clicking through windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1276270/clicking-through-windows), though it seems to be unanswered and I thought a little more information of my own might help close the case.

System Information:

- Windows 10 Pro - Version 10.0.16299 (Semi-Annual Channel)
- Nvidia Video Driver 390.65 (Latest)

So far I've tried:

- Running DISM, SFC, and chkdsk.
- Reinstalling some offending applications.

Comment: I suggest you put some transitions in the movie.  Adding Text to the video, indicating where you are interacting with the program, would be helpful to identify the problem.  Like I said 0.25 playback I don't see anything that isn't suppose to happen.

Comment: @Ramhound I have replaced the video that you initially commented on. Instead of clicking, however, I demonstrated hover events malfunctioning. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you mentioned now has answers. [This one](https://superuser.com/a/1295077/873812) suggests, pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice seems to fix the problem temporarily.