# Selecting maximized window sometimes selects windows behind it

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sublime-text-2, mysql-workbench

To better explain the issue, lets say that on one monitor I have MySQL Workbench maximized and on the second monitor I have a browser (Chrome) open. Lets say I also have Windows Explorer open, it is not maximized, and it is hidden behind MySQL workbench. Sometimes, when I switch from my browser immediately to MySQL Workbench, my click will not register in MySQL Workbench but in Windows Explorer. This brings Windows explorer to the front. This will continue to happen with all the applications that are hidden behind MySQL Workbench until I minimize then re-maximize MySQL workbench.

For me this is happening on both MySQL Workbench and Sublime Text, but after a little research I think this (or an issue very similar) is happening with Steam as well.

This only started happening after Windows 10 installed the latest update, and this issue appears to be intermittent. So far I have only experienced this issue when dealing with maximized windows where they have non-maximized windows behind them, but not enough to confirm that those are the only circumstances that it will happen.

**Versions:**

- Windows 10 Home - v1709 (Build 16299.125)
- Sublime Text 3 Build 3143
- MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this might be an issue with post-1709 versions of Windows. As mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1295077/873812), pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice seems to solve the problem temporarily.