# Black 'hole' strip at top of windows

Tags: windows-10

My PC keeps getting black 'holes' across the top of the screen, meaning that I can't click on application tool bars:

[image]

This isn't just a graphical issue, if I click on this blank area, the mouse click goes through the active application to whatever is underneath. Also, I can drag non-affected windows over the top:

[image]

This is affecting Internet Explorer, Opera, and PDF X-Change Editor. With the web browsers, I can hit F11 to go full screen to remove the black bar, and then again to go back to normal window mode and everything is fixed. With PDF X-Change Editor, F11 full screen looks fine, but on returning to window mode the black/white bar is back.

This is a desktop PC using an NVIDIA GTX 1080, with latest drivers downloaded an hour ago.

Any suggestions / solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Clicking through windows](https://superuser.com/q/1276270/655861) resetting the video driver via the shortcut  CTRL+Shift+Win+B remediates the problem.